# Why shouldn't I upload firmware update images via Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireless-networking, firmware

Whenever I download a firmware update file for a Wireless Router the documentation / manual warns users not to upload the file over Wireless connection, but to connect via uTP cable instead. The reason for this is apparently that the uploaded file can become corrupted if using Wireless.

Now this is the part I don't understand. If the upload is being done via an HTML form which uses HTTP connections (TCP), if there are errors, the TCP protocol should take care of resending those packets and reassembling them on the other side. So if using TCP there should be no difference between using Wi-Fi or Ethernet. Is there some other reason that I might be missing? Why shouldn't I use WiFi for uploading firmware update binary files?

Answer (score 1):

In general, wired connections are most of the time more reliable than Wifi connections.

A wifi connections has more ways of failing than a wired one, mainly due to the fact that it's radio frequency based.
- interference
- low quality signal
- loss of signal due to environment
- etc.

A wired connection usually keeps a connection active as long as it is physically connected to something. The only way to alter or break the connection would be to physically unplug or damage the cable.

Or maybe they reset the wifi controller in the firmware upgrade routine, which could lead to a failure. Who knows.

The company and/or person that made the documentation probably wanted to give their lawyers a warranty against any possible way of bricking a device while upgrading firmware on one of their devices. Doing it over wifi shouldn't be a problem but they (or even I) won't be held responsible if you brick your device while upgrading your wifi router over wifi because they told you to use a wired connection.

Those manuals are mainly made up so that they can protect themselves in case of a customer coming back at them. If you don't use the device as they intended you to, they can't be held responsible for it to break.